# Some windows not showing up in Alt + Tab

Tags: firefox, chromium, application-switcher

I installed Chromium from the Software Centre yesterday and realised it wasn't showing up in Alt + Tab switching so I decided to go back to Firefox. It turns out Firefox also doesn't show up, but only since installing Chromium.

---

[image: Screenshot displaying the problem, Firefox is open but not showing up in Alt + Tab]

---

Also, neither show up as open in the launcher (no little triangle) so switching using that just opens a new window. Gimp has the same problem. Any ideas for a fix?

---

[image: Screenshot showing no triangle for Firefox but showing one for Thunderbird]

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Press Alt-F2

Type `unity --replace`

Comment: You forgot to mention that this command will close all open programs and log you out.

Comment: It doesn't for me?

Comment: On Ubuntu 16.04 LTS, the parameter 'replace'  is deprecated and has no effect.